# Android emulator is not getting open

Tags: android, android-emulator, haxm

When I am try to open my android emulator, getting below error

---

```
distrib/android-emugl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glAttachShader:187 error 0x501

distrib/android-emugl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glAttachShader:187 error 0x501

TextureDraw: Could not create/link program: 
creating window 79 106 321 535

emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check

draw: no program
```

---

Emulator details:
API 17
CPU armeabi-v7a
RAM - 746 MB

I have core 2 duo 1.4 GHz Dell Inspiron system

When I try to install HAX it says my system does not support Virtualization. I tried to start it from BIOS but I guess my system doesn't have it.

Comment: HAX requires particular CPU features. Very possible that your host CPU doesn't support it. The error messages seem to be more related to "Use Host GPU" than HAX, however.

Comment: So were you able to get an emulator running or not at all. If emulator was running and not now, does a newly created emulator work. Also are you using two monitors?

Comment: No I am not able to get it running. I have installed new setup of android studio but no use. Newly created emulators are also not working.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many different things this is what finally worked for me.

1. Delete all existing AVDs
2. [Uninstall Intel HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows)
3. Create a new AVD and it will make you install HAXM
4. Create a new AVD

Worked for following config:

```
Name: Nexus_5X_API_19 CPU/ABI: Google APIs (x86 System Image) Intel Atom (x86) Path: C:\Android\.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_19.avd Target: google_apis_x86 [Google APIs (x86 System Image)] (API level 19) Skin: nexus_5x SD Card: 100M hw.dPad: no
```

However, similar config for API 21 still getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

Same things happen with me when i format my PC and after install OS and install the Android Studio. I have tried [@farrukh najmi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45898675/6533853) answer and i have to extends the some more information on it.

1] Delete the avd from `.../User/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_26.avd folder and file`
2] Restart android studio.
3] Create new AVD.

and start that new AVD and its work form me. I hope this information will help some one

Answer (score -1):

My suggest is to have a look at Genymotion, it will offers you a better experience.

Comment: And you are not short of reputation numbers that you can't suggest in a comment box..

Comment: @helloimyourmind http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33382933/genymotion-unable-to-connect-to-virtual-device  ny suggestion ?

Comment: This answer was not relevant or helpful for getting the emulator from android sdk working as asked in op.